# Using JavaScript to communicate a button press to another page?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have 5 HTML buttons on a page.  I want to pass the value of the particular button that has been clicked through a query string on second page through JavaScript.  Please advise me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm cheating and using jQuery, just to illustrate the concept.

You have your 5 buttons with their own unique IDs and all of them have a class of "button"

On clicking any of them, the browser will navigate to "http://mydomain.com/nextpage" with the "buttonclicked" parameter in the query string set to the ID of the button that was clicked.

```
$('.button').click(function(){
  window.location.href = "http://mydomain.com/nextpage?buttonclicked="+this.id;
});
```

Interactive example: http://jsfiddle.net/6EZvG/

Comment: If it has to be done with JavaScript, this seems like it would be the best idea -- though I think I would use the data-* attribute and put the query string inside that, something like data-qsv="query_string_value".

Comment: @RussellUresti that's a great idea, looser coupling

Answer (score 1):

This only makes sense to me as non-javascript:

```
<form action="" method="get">
   <input type="submit" name="button" value="button 1" />
   <input type="submit" name="button" value="button 2" />
   <input type="submit" name="button" value="button 3" />
   <input type="submit" name="button" value="button 4" />
   <input type="submit" name="button" value="button 5" />
</form>
```

That's plain old HTML's way of passing buttons on the QS, could you clarify / give example of your situation?

Answer (score 0):

IF you are having 5 submit buttons then you can submit and get the values using GET methods.If that is not the case and you need to specify how are you reaching the other pages.